# How to check if fields are filled in a specific div

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I have a multi-part form, built using `bootstrap` `tab-content`. Now I want to check if all the required fields are filled before moving to the next tab and show alert message and redirect back to the previous if tries to move to next tab.
Here is a Screen shot of what my form looks like:
[image]

Now I want to check if all the required inputs of `basic_info` div are filled before moving to any other div.

I have done the following to check the fields individually. But it actually checks all the field.

```
$('#li_2').click(function(){
        $('#submit_section').hide();
        var length = $('.required').length;
        var value = $('.required').filter(function () {
            return this.value != '';
        });

        if (value.length>=0 && (value.length !== length)) {
            alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
        }
    });
```

Now how can I check the full div at once and stay on that div if the fields are not filled.

Comment: Can you share minimal running example ?

Comment: @rian zaman nice solution you made. I think you could easily get what you want in this rows: var length ... and var value... just add the id of the div to the selector here: $('.required'). so it will be someting like $('#mydiv .required').

Comment: @Hans Dash Thanks man. Your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is small example to get idea, to validate first then after to allow user to go next tab, I just used single input element you can add your all form validation here.

```js
$("#home_form input").on("keyup",function(){
  if($(this).val().trim()){
    $("a[href='#menu1']").attr("data-toggle","tab").removeClass('disabled');
  }else{
    $("a[href='#menu1'],a[href='#menu2']").removeAttr("data-toggle").addClass('disabled');
    $("#menu1_form")[0].reset();
    $("#menu2_form")[0].reset();
  }
});

$("#menu1_form input").on("keyup",function(){
  if($(this).val().trim()){
    $("a[href='#menu2']").attr("data-toggle","tab").removeClass('disabled');
  }else{
    $("a[href='#menu2']").removeAttr("data-toggle").addClass('disabled').val("");
    $("#menu2_form")[0].reset();
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs li{
  margin-left:10px;
}
.disabled{
  color:grey !important;
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="disabled" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="disabled" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <form id="home_form">
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <form id="menu1_form">
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <form id="menu2_form">
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you go previous tab and empty input text it will again disable the subsequent tab. you can use number to like `#form1` or `#form2`... to move next-previous easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code helped me understand what I had to do. Tho I did not have separate forms. I had only one.
But I have combined @Hans Dashs' solution and your solution to make it work. It works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 0):

It checks all the fields because they all have the class 'required'. You can try using an id or a different class name for each to identify them singly and then check the length of their value.
Let me put an example of an instance:

```
<input name="firstName" id= "fName"class="required" type="text"/>
<input name="lastName" id= "lName" class="required" type="text"/>

$('#li_2').click(function(){
    $('#submit_section').hide();
    var length = $('.required#fName').length;
    var value = $('.required#fName').filter(function () {
        return this.value != '';
    });

    if (value.length>=0 && (value.length !== length)) {
        alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
    }
});
```

This is just to check out a field. You can try using a for loop to get all elements with the '.required' class and then checking the length of the value of each and displaying a result.